# Algorithm to create a linked list from a set of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am looking for an algorithm to create a linked list from a set of nodes. For example, let's assume a node is an airline ticket from a source point to destination. (e.g., Chicago to Detroit) and there are several airline tickets. Assuming all these airline tickets are jumbled, what is the best way to determine the entire journey path. 
If there are 5 airline tickets like Chicago->Detroit, Denver->Chicago, Detroit->DC, DC->New York, San Jose->Denver, the algorithm should be able to come up with the correct start to end path.

San Jose -> Denver -> Chicago -> Detroit -> DC -> New York

Comment: Thank you everyone for the solutions. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are guaranteed that the nodes will form a single path (ie, maximum indegree is 1, maximum outdegree is 1, exactly one node has indegree 0, exactly one node has outdegree 0), then you could do the following:

- Construct two hashes: `in_cities` and `out_cities`
- For every node `A -> B`, add it to `in_cities` with key `A` and `out_cities` with key `B`
- Pick a node arbitrarily, call it `S`
- Have `curr` point to `S`.  While the source city of `curr` is in `out_cities`, insert the corresponding node in the beginning of the path.  Update `curr` to point to this node.
- Have `curr` point to `S`.  While the destination city of `curr` is in `in_cities`, add the corresponding node to the end of the path.  Update `curr` to point to this node.

Now you are done, in linear time with respect to the total number of cities.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linked-list question; it's a [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) question.

A graph is mathematically defined as a set of vertices, and a set of edges, which are pairs of vertices that are defined as "adjacent". The edges can also be defined to be [directed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) (such is the case in your scenario).

A [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph is a sequence of vertices such that there is an edge from each of the vertices to the next vertex in the sequence.

Adjacency relationship are commonly represented in one of two ways: [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) (a simple 2D array), or an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) (which uses a linked list), but problems and solutions can be defined regardless of representation (though it does have an effect on complexity).

The [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), for example, assigns weights to the edges, and require a path between two nodes whose total weight is minimized. The classic solution taught in computer science course is [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Most good algorithm books have a chapter on elementary graph theory.

---

Having said all that, there is a special kind of graph that is called a [path graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph), which may be what your input graph is (it can only be confirmed once all the assumptions of the problems are made explicit). If your input graph is of this simple type, then an easy solution to your problem exists (see [danben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734697/algorithm-to-create-a-linked-list-from-a-set-of-nodes/2734732#2734732)).

I will present the same algorithm in pseudocode form:

```
LET pred BE a MAP City=>City // "predecessor"
LET succ BE a MAP City=>City // "successor"

// build pred and succ
FOR EACH Ticket(City A, City B) DO
   pred[B] = A
   succ[A] = B

// find the starting city, i.e. one that doesn't have a pred
LET C BE any City
WHILE pred[C] != NULL
  C = pred[C]

// keep going until you reach the end
WHILE C != NULL
  PRINT C
  C = succ[C]
```

With a good `MAP` implementation, this is `O(N)` where `N` is the number of tickets.